# Using linear referencing in ArcGIS to plot line data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I have just started using the linear referencing tools in ArcGIS 10.2 but I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to plot schemes as line data on to our road network layer which is also line data using start and end points (almost like routes).

This is what I have so far :

1. I've successfully created a route layer from our road network line data. This layer is split into around a 1000 sections ranging from 50m to 2500m with each having there own SECTION_ID.
2. I have a table which has numerous schemes in each with the following attributes : SCHEME_NAME, START_SECTION_ID, START_CHAINAGE (How far into that section in meters), END_SECTION_ID, END_CHAINAGE_ID (How far into that section in meters).

I'm using the **Make Route Event Layer** tool to create the schemes on the road network layer using the SECTION_ID as the route identifier field. The problem is I can only seem to plot the schemes which start and end in the same SECTION_ID as there is no option to provide an additional end route identifier field.

I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way so can anyone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linear Referencing routes should normally be continuous for the entire linear feature (i.e., an entire road, stream course, etc.) to create the maximum set of measures.  Routes work best if they are simple.  Branching should generally be avoided by creating separate routes (either broken into separate routes beginning at the branch point or with multiple routes overlapping on the main course that each continue along only one of the separate branches).  Normally Linear Referencing is best for facility management on single roads.

There is no direct way to define an event using measures that are derived relative to other events as their starting point.  If you have multiple Segment IDs that all fall on the same road, those Segment IDs should be defined as events.  The events you described that you want to set up are events defined relative to the Segment ID set of events, but your Routes are unable to extrapolate measures this way.

I have faced the same thing for my event limits that are all defined relative to cross street intersections.  To solve that I have created a set of events for each intersection street name pair in a separate table.  Using joins I can link derivative events to each intersection through a common street name pair field, transfer the intersection's point measure to my event and then apply offsets to that measure in another field to define a position on the underlying route both reference.  It is not a simple process to do this, but it can be done.  Ultimately I programmed an interface to let users define events based on intersections and the program does the two look ups in the intersection table to derive the two limit measures.

If you actually want to follow any possible path along a line network that can begin and end on any road in the network you should use Network Analyst to build your lines into a Network dataset.  Then you can set start and end points at any position along your network and have solvers create routes that connect them based on criteria (shortest distance, shortest time, multiple stops, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive info Richard, I have it a lot clearer in my mind now. I feared Network Analyst may be the way to go! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read this manual:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/linear-referencing-tutorial.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link but I've already seen document.

Answer (score 0):

A linear event can be built on a single route. 
When building routes, you need to specify the Route ID field.
To build route events, your table must contain the same route ID and From and To measure.

Comment: Oh ok I see, maybe I need a different approach then as the start and end points can potentially be on separate route ID's. Thanks